# How to pass parameters thru URL?

Tags: urls, parameter, input

I have two input text box, one recaptcha and submit button.

I want to check if the values that inputted by the user are in the database and if the recaptcha is checked. But the database is located on another server.

The one server, is running Wordpress which is the form is located. Here's the [link](http://goo.gl/f81Yox)

The second server, where the database is located and this server doing checking of the inputted values.

How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you tell us about your setup? Are both servers running WordPress? Which server is the form on? Which server is the Database on? Which server is doing the checking? What's the reason this isn't just on the same server/box?

Comment: @TomJNowell please see the updated question. The server where the wordpress installed can't handled large of data. While the second server, can do that.